# Wagtail Plain Text Template Output

Tags: wagtail

What's the best method for inserting text into a template that's not wrapped in a div ([discussed here](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues/1214))? CharBlock, TextBlock, and RichTextField all insert divs which play havoc with the website template I'm working with, for example: `<div class="rich-text"></div>`. I also looked at [DraftTail](https://github.com/springload/wagtaildraftail), but it's not ready for production.

I'm assuming I need a filter to strip the enclosing html. Is there an example someone can point me to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CharBlock` and `TextBlock` do not insert divs of their own (only `RichTextBlock` does). The wrapper div you're seeing is probably the one that StreamField inserts around each block in the default rendering (e.g. for a StreamField named `body`, using `{{ page.body }}` to output the field value all in one go - if you want to override this, you can loop over `page.body` instead:

```
{% load wagtailcore_tags %}

{% for block in page.body %}
    {% include_block block %}
{% endfor %}
```